# Error `Missing \endcsname inserted` (Bibliography, bibtex)

Tags: bibtex, debugging

While adding references in my thesis paper, I copied the following BibTex from google scholar:

```
    @article{aygunoǧlu2009introduction,
  title={Introduction to fuzzy soft groups},
  author={Ayg{\"u}noǧlu, Abd{\"u}lkadir and Ayg{\"u}n, Halis},
  journal={Computers \& Mathematics with Applications},
  volume={58},
  number={6},
  pages={1279--1286},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

After  pasting the same in the .bib file which I created, I added the label key in the original .tex file. But I am getting the following error:

```
line 52: Missing \endcsname inserted. ...on 2.15} \cite{aygunoǧlu2009introduction}
```

Please suggest me how to fix it.

Comment: Change the key `aygunoǧlu2009introduction` to `aygunoglu2009introduction` and do the same in the citation.

Comment: Thank you sir it's done. I may sound lame but still how did you figure out the error so easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The citation keys should not have special characters: sticking to letters (without accents) and digits is best.

You could have `aygunoǧlu2009introduction` if you compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, but the bib file would not be really portable.

So the best solution is to change the key from

```
aygunoǧlu2009introduction
```

to

```
aygunoglu2009introduction
```

If you compile with `pdflatex` it's also better to change the author name to

```
Ayg{\"u}no{\u{g}}lu
```

so sorting will not give problems.